# Django - What is the most pythonic way to update my page via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I want someone with "manager" access to be able to view all user activity, and the page should continuously update after every couple of minutes via AJAX.

Should I have both, users and AJAX requests, get sent to the same URL? Or should I have two separate URLs (one that renders a template and another one that only returns JSON)?

Here is how I imagine this should be structured:

```py
def index(request):
   context = get_user_activity()

   if request.is_ajax():
      # Process the data and only return updates they don't already have on their screen
      return JsonResponse(updated_data, status = 200)

   return render(request, 'activity.html', context)
```

```
domain.com/activity/           <-- Users and AJAX requests are sent to this url

OR

domain.com/activity/           <-- Users get sent to this page
domain.com/api/update-activity <-- AJAX requests are made to this URL
```